# how to add snap scroll and aos to the same component

Tags: html, css, angular, animation, frontend

so i am creating a component and trying to implement snap scroll and aos both but only one is working let me provide the code and ill explain the problem

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    /* overflow: auto; */
  }
  
  .full-page-scroll-main-container {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }
  
  .full-page-scroll-main-container section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
  }  
.parallax {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parallax img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.parallax .btn-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; /* Adjust the bottom value as needed */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: x-large;
}  
.two {
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .two .btn-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  
  .two .btn-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  .three {
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .three .btn-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  
  .three .btn-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  .four {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .four .btn-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
  
  .four .btn-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: x-large;
  }
```

```html
 <body>
      <div class="full-page-scroll-main-container">
        <section class="parallax" #parallaxSection>
          <img src="assets/stars-main-page-fotor-bg-remover-2023052010134.png" id="main-stars" />
          <img src="assets/base-main-page-fotor-bg-remover-2023052010045.png" id="main-base" />
          <img src="assets/Brand-name-main-page-fotor-bg-remover-2023052010113.png" id="main-brand" />
          <img src="assets/lights-main-page-fotor-bg-remover-2023052010344.png" id="main-lights" />
          <button class="btn btn-bottom" (click)="scrollToNextSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></button>
        </section>
        <section class="two">
          <button class="btn btn-top" (click)="scrollToPreviousSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-up"></i></button>
          <h1 data-aos="fade-up">Second Page</h1>
          <button class="btn btn-bottom" (click)="scrollToNextSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></button>
        </section>
        <section class="three">
          <button class="btn btn-top" (click)="scrollToPreviousSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-up"></i></button>
          <h1 data-aos="fade-up">Third Page</h1>
          <button class="btn btn-bottom" (click)="scrollToNextSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></button>
        </section>
        <section class="four">
          <button class="btn btn-top" (click)="scrollToPreviousSection($event)"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-up"></i></button>
          <h1>Fourth Page</h1>
        </section>    
      </div>
    </body>
```

```
    import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare let AOS: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('parallaxSection') parallaxSection!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){ 
    console.log(AOS); // loaded script
   }
  ngOnInit() {
    AOS.init();
    const stars = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#main-stars');
    const base = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#main-base');
    const brand = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#main-brand');
    const lights = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#main-lights');
  
    const container = document.querySelector('.full-page-scroll-main-container');
  
    if (container) {
      container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let value = container.scrollTop;
  
        stars.style.left = value * -2 + 'px';
        base.style.left = value * -1 + 'px';
        brand.style.left = value * 1 + 'px';
      });
    }
  }
  scrollToNextSection(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const nextSection = (event.target as HTMLElement).closest('section')?.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextSection) {
      nextSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
    }
  }
  
  scrollToPreviousSection(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const previousSection = (event.target as HTMLElement).closest('section')?.previousElementSibling;
    if (previousSection) {
      previousSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
    }
  }
  
  }
```

Now let me explain everything i want a page that has 4 different section each being scrolled thought each other using snap scroll now that snap scroll happens not via scrolling but using mouse clicks of the buttons that are added in the HTML that happening i also want the parallax effect when scrolling or going away from a section or the aos fade in effect when scrolling or going to a section even if there is no snapscroll in the css the snap scroll works via the methods in css The problem is that one of the two things is happening either the aos or the parallax effect works in the code above aos is available the elements fade in when they are coming into the screen but the parallax effect stops working if i remove the comments from overflow-y: hidden; property on the 13 line of css the parallax effect starts to work but any element containng the aos directives disappears i feel like i am over complicating things and there is an easy way to do it i just want the aos and parallax effect both to work and if any one can also i want no scroll bars on this component as well if any one can help that be the world to me thankyou very much